# Prove that $\mu:G\times G \rightarrow G$ is a homomorphism if and only if $G$ is abelian.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Given $\mu:G\times G$ be the operation on a group $G$; that is, $\mu (a,b)=ab$.  Prove that $\mu$ is a homomorphism if and only if $G$ is abelian.

I have no problem on proving the necessary condition but on proving the sufficient condition.

Let $(a,b),(a',b')\in G\times G$
Suppose $\mu$ is a homomorphism.
Then $\mu((a,b)(a',b'))=\mu(a,b)\mu(a',b')$
$\mu(aa',bb')=aba'b'$
$aa'bb'=aba'b'$
$a'b=b'a$

I can only show $a'$ commute with $b$ but what I need to show is $ab$ commute with $a'b'$.

Comment: If G is abelian it trivially holds. Your proof shows that G is abelian for the equation you have is true for arbitrary a' and b'.

Comment: Note that $(a, 1), (1, b)\in G\times G$ commute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**.  Your aim is wrong: you don't need to show that $ab$ commutes with $a'b'$, you need to show that $a$ commutes with $b$.  So,
$$\mu((a,b)(a,b))=\cdots\,?$$